# Tree map by categories

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a tree-map from categories.

I have the categories (I have a lot of categories and I want to remove duplicates and show them in a tree-map view)

```
$cat = array(
    "Sneakers/Men",
    "Sneakers/Women",
    "Accessories/Jewellery/Men",
    "Accessories/Jewellery/Women",
    "Accessories/Jewellery/Men
");
```

...and I want them like this

```
$categories = array(
    "Sneakers" => array(
        "Men" => array(),
        "Women" => array()
    ),
    "Accessories" => array(
        "Jewellery" => array(
            "Men" => array(),
            "Women" => array()
        )
    )
);
```

to print them like this

```
- Sneakers
-- Men
-- Women

- Accessories
-- Jewellery
--- Men
--- Women
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
$cat = array(
    "Sneakers/Men",
    "Sneakers/Women",
    "Accessories/Jewellery/Men",
    "Accessories/Jewellery/Women",
    "Accessories/Jewellery/Men
");

function buildTree($categories, $result = []){
    $temp = [];
    foreach($categories as $categoryString){
        $catParts = explode('/',$categoryString);
        if(count($catParts) > 1){
            $temp[$catParts[0]][] = str_replace($catParts[0].'/','',$categoryString);
        } else {
            $temp[$catParts[0]] = [];
        }

    }
    foreach($temp as $elemName => $elemVal){
        $result[$elemName] = buildTree($elemVal);
    }
    return $result;
}

var_dump(buildTree($cat));
```

Comment: That's what I searched for. Thank you @Tomasz Winter.

Comment: is it a way to find out how many categories were duplicates? for example "Accessories/Jewellery/Men" is for 2 times and the result array to be like array("accessories" => array("jewellery" => array("men" => 2)))

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way is to use references, like this:

```
$out = [];
foreach ($cat as $str) {
    $lookup =& $out;
    foreach (explode("/", $str) as $part) {
        $lookup =& $lookup[$part];
        if (!isset($lookup)) {
            $lookup = [];
        }
    }
}
```

`$lookup` initially refers to the whole expected result, then the reference is extended at each step to follow the path of nested members.

Note that each new member added looks like `member-name => []`, so that actually even final leaves are arrays: it may seem a bit weird, but is a pretty way to have a reduced code (each member is always ready to receive children).

And it's not a difficulty, though, to use the resulting array to then print it like the OP asked:

```
function nest_print($src, $level = 0) {
    $prefix = '<br />' . str_repeat('- ', ++$level);
    foreach ($src as $key => $val) {
      echo $prefix . $key;
      if ($val) {
          nest_print($val, $level);
      }
    }
}

nest_print($out);
```

---

EDIT

Here is an alternate solution, including the count of final leaves, as asked by the OP in his comment:

```
$out = [];
foreach ($cat as $str) {
    $lookup =& $out;
    $parts = explode("/", $str);
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        $lookup =& $lookup[$part];
        if (!isset($lookup)) {
            $lookup = [];
        }
        // when $part is a final leaf, count its occurrences
        if ($part == end($parts)) {
            $lookup = is_array($lookup) ? 1 : ++$lookup;
        }
    }
}
```

(might likely be improved in a more elegant way, though)

And here is how to modify the print-result snippet accordingly:

```
function nest_print($src, $level = 0) {
    $prefix = '<br />' . str_repeat('- ', ++$level);
    foreach ($src as $key => $val) {
      echo $prefix . $key;
      if (is_array($val)) {
          nest_print($val, $level);
      } else {
          echo ': ' . $val;
      }
    }
}

nest_print($out);
```

Comment: is it a way to find out how many categories were duplicates? for example "Accessories/Jewellery/Men" is for 2 times and the result array to be like array("accessories" => array("jewellery" => array("men" => 2)))

Comment: wow, thank you! you rock! it's works well but i have this error Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in on this line "$lookup =& $lookup[$part];"

Comment: @MadalinAlexandru Weird... I just checked with the exact same snippet than above and I don't get any error. Do you get it once or as many as steps processed? Anyway, can you add `echo '<br />' . $str . ' -> ' . $part;` just before the `$lookup =& $lookup[$part];` line, and report what you get?

Comment: Try to change $cat = array(
"Sneakers/Men",
"Sneakers/Women",
"Accessories/Jewellery/Men",
"Accessories/Jewellery/Men",
"Accessories/Jewellery/Women",
"Accessories/Jewellery/Men/Adidas/Add"); and you 'll get the error

Comment: @MadalinAlexandru Yep! This is pretty normal: in your enriched source data you now have several `Accessories/Jewellery/Men` which are not final leaves (while previous ones were). Here is a conceptual choice: as soon as you decided that a final leaf will contain its number of occurrences (so being a different kind of object than intermediate categories) you can't want a category be both a final leaf AND a container for sub-categories! So the solution is either: 1) you don't count final leaves any longer (they remain possible containers); 2) or you carefully use proper reserved names for leaves.